# Is there is difference between "homozygosity" and "homozygosis"?

Tags: genetics, terminology

Are these just two terms for the same phenomenon, i.e., the state of being homozygous? [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homozygosis) says so, but I know dictionaries sometimes miss the nuance of scientific terms. If they are indeed synonyms, it seems *homozygosity* has won out, according to [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=homozygosity%2Chomozygosis&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chomozygosity%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhomozygosity%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHomozygosity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chomozygosis%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhomozygosis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHomozygosis%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The question is currently receiving close votes because it looks like a homework question. You should try to show your attempt at answering your question if you want to avoid having your question closed.

Comment: Ha, fair enough. I am not student. I am a hamster breeder with a keen interest in genetics. I had this question because I only saw the term "homozygosis" in publications from several decades ago. I edited the question as suggested.

Comment: I edited my question to show my attempt at an answer. Can it be returned to open status?

Comment: I made the changes that were requested. Why was this question closed?

Answer (score 2):

*Homozygosis* and *homozygosity* are NOT synonymous. The two terms refer to the same concept though.

**Homozygote**

An indivdidual or a cell is said to be *homozygote* for a particular gene (or any DNA sequence) when identical [alleles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele) of the gene are present on both [homologous chromosomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homologous_chromosome). ([Wikipedia > Zygosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygosity)).

**Homozygosis**

*Homozygosis* is the state of being *homozygote* ([Wright 1933](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1086014/)) for a particular gene (or any DNA sequence). According to [freedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/homozygosis), *homozygosis* may also refer to the process of formation of a *homozygote*. I have never encountered this sense in the literature though. As you found out by yourself, *Homozygosis* is a term that is rarely used in the literature (in comparison to *homozygote* and *homozygosity*)

---

**Expected Homozygosity**

*Expected Homozygosity* is the probability of two randomly sampled alleles (in a population and at a given [locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_(genetics))) to be [identical by descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_by_descent).

**Expected homozygosity and Expected heterozygosity**

As shown in [Nei 1973](http://www.pnas.org/content/70/12/3321.short), the mathematical expression of expected homozygosity $Ho$ is

$$Ho = \sum_{a=1}^{n} x_a^2$$

where $n$ is the number of alleles and $x_a$ is the frequency of the allele $a$.

It is more common to use the concept of *expected heterozygosity* $He$ (a.k.a. gene diversity) rather than the one of *expected homozygosity* $Ho$. By definition, $He=1-Ho$, that is

$$He =1- \sum_{a=1}^{n} x_a^2$$

In the special case of a bi-allelic locus, and replacing the two allele frequencies $x=1$ and $x=2$ by $p$ and $q=1-p$, the above formulations becomes

$$Ho = p^2 + q^2$$
$$He = 1 - (p^2 + q^2) = 2pq$$

**Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium**

Under the [Hardy-Weinberg assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Weinberg_principle#Deviations_from_Hardy.E2.80.93Weinberg_equilibrium), the observed frequency of heterozygote (a.k.a. observed heterozygosity) is equal to the expected heterozygosity and observed frequency of homozygotes (a.k.a. observed homozygosity) is equal to the expected homozygosity.